# Parameterised query asp classic missing operand error

Tags: asp-classic, parameters, parameterized

I am trying to get a paramterised query to work in asp classic. Any help appreciated
Here is the error

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro error '80040e14' 
>   Missing operand. 
>   /portal/jobportal/getaddress1.asp, line 141

```
function paramQuery()

code = ucase(request.querystring("code"))
stype = request.querystring("type")
cAddressType = request.querystring("caddresstype")


Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
Set cmd = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

If IsObject(Session("portal_conn")) Then
    Set conn = Session("portal_conn")
Else
    Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cConnString = "Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source="+session("portaldata")+"portal.dbc" 
    conn.open cConnString,"",""
    Set Session("portal_conn") = conn
end if

cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.Prepared = true
cmd.CommandType = 1
cmd.CommandText =  "SELECT * from uaddress where userid = "+cstr(session("userid"))+" and upper(name) like ? + % "+" and type = '"+ trim(cAddresstype)+"' order by add1"

set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@name",200,2,40)
cmd.Parameters.append param1
cmd.Parameters("@name") = code
cmd.Execute() <-- missing operand error
rs.Open cmd

end function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using parameter for SQL `like` clause you need to pass the `%` as part of the parameter value.

Also to protect against SQL Injection attacks you really better use parameters for the other values as well:

```
cmd.CommandText =  "SELECT * FROM uaddress WHERE userid=? AND UPPER(name) LIKE ? AND type=? ORDER BY add1"

set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@id", 200, 2, 40)
cmd.Parameters.append param1
cmd.Parameters("@id") = cstr(session("userid"))

set param2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@name", 200, 2, 40)
cmd.Parameters.append param2
cmd.Parameters("@name") = "%" & code & "%"

set param3 = cmd.CreateParameter("@type", 200, 2, 40)
cmd.Parameters.append param3
cmd.Parameters("@type") = trim(cAddresstype)

cmd.Execute()
```

Comment: Is this a FoxPro-specific thing?  I've used parameters for `LIKE` clauses before with other databases.

Comment: @Cheran I read long ago something and it sticked - my bad. Will update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the `%` character:

```
... +" and upper(name) like ? + '%' "+ ...
```

Comment: I think it will still not work, since you have to pass the `%` as part of the parameter itself but it's not totally wrong like I thought before. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like VFP does not support named parameters , just add your params in the order that apears in the query by using (?) instead of the named param and it will work.

instead of :

```
cmd.Parameters("@name") = code
```

Use :

```
cmd.Parameters("?") = code
```